# max match function for Homework

Tags: javascript

Create an html page, add 3 text boxes in which the user will input 3 numbers :a,b,c
Add a button that, on click, will calculate the maximum number of the three. The result will be displayed in an alert. The program should not crash if the user does not input one or two numbers.

**Cases:**

-If no number is introduced then a message should be displayed asking the user to input at least on number.

-If only one number of the three is introduced, that number is the maximum number.

-If two numbers are introduced then it should be displayed the maximum of the two.

-If three numbers are introduced then it should be displayed the maximum of the three.

**What I did**

```
{
    var a = getNumber1 ();
    var b = getNumber2 ();
    var c = getNumber3 ();
    
    
    if(Number.isNaN(a) && Number.isNaN(b) && Number.isNaN(c))
    alert("please input a number");
    
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
var max;
    if ((!Number.isNaN(a)) && Number.isNaN(b) && Number.isNaN(c))
        {
            max=a;
 alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }
    else if (Number.isNaN(a) && (!Number.isNaN(b)) && Number.isNaN(c))
        {
            max=b;
 alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }

    else if (Number.isNaN(a) && Number.isNaN(b) && (!Number.isNaN(c)))
        {
            max=c;
 alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    if ((!Number.isNaN(a)) && !Number.isNaN(b) && Number.isNaN(c) && a>b)
        {
            max=a;
            alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }
    else if (b>a)
        {
            max=b;
            alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }
        
            if ((!Number.isNaN(a)) && Number.isNaN(b) && !Number.isNaN(c) && a>c)
        {
            max=a;
            alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }
    else if (c>a)
        {
            max=c;
            alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }
            
        if ((Number.isNaN(a)) && !Number.isNaN(b) && !Number.isNaN(c) && b>c)
        {
            max=b;
            alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }
    else if (c>b)
        {
            max=c;
            alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if ((!Number.isNaN(a)) && !Number.isNaN(b) && !Number.isNaN(c) && a>b,c)
        {
            max=a;
            alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }
    else if (b>a,c)
        {
            max=b;
            alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }   
    
    else if (c>a,b)
        {
            max=c;
            alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function getNumber1()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("Number1"); 
    return parseInt(a.value);
}
function getNumber2()
{
    var b = document.getElementById("Number2"); 
    return parseInt(b.value);
}
function getNumber3()
{
    var c = document.getElementById("Number3"); 
    return parseInt(c.value);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Almost all the code works except the last part

```
       {
           max=a;
           alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
       }
   else if (b>a,c)
       {
           max=b;
           alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
       }   
   
   else if (c>a,b)
       {
           max=c;
           alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
       } 


I think that the first third part of the code (-If two numbers are introduced then it should be displayed the maximum of the two.) gets into the fourth part of the code because if i have
a=1 b=2 c=3
i have the second code that tell me that if b>a b=max but the third code tell me that c>a/b so c=max so i have 2 max
even more
```

Comment: If no number is introduced then a message should be displayed asking the user to input at least on number. (srry for that)

Comment: `parseInt()` never returns `null`. What it returns for non-numbers is `NaN`. You can check if a value is `NaN` with `Number.isNaN(value)`.

Comment: i also did 
` if(a==NaN&& b==NaN&& c==NaN)
 alert("please input a number");
 
 else if(a!=NaN && b!=NaN && c!=NaN)
 alert("your value is " + a + " "+b+" "+c);`

Comment: `value == NaN` won't work, because in JavaScript `NaN != NaN` (I know, it's quirky).

Comment: So i should use  `if(isNaN(a) && isNaN(b) && isNaN(c)) ` ?
What should i use if my input is a number (syntax)

Comment: It's `Number.isNan(a)`, not `isNaN(a)`. There is indeed a global function called `isNaN()`, but it works a bit differently.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share what you've tried so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Sure thing :)
I already did something and i m at the last question "-If three numbers are introduced then it should be displayed the maximum of the three."
The code is (to long to put here lol)

Comment: -If three numbers are introduced then it should be displayed the maximum of the three.
now i need to do that (i ll add another comment with what i did)

Comment: `  if ((!Number.isNaN(a)) && !Number.isNaN(b) && !Number.isNaN(c) && a>b,c)
        {
            max=a;
   alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        }
 else if (b>a,c)
  {
   max=b;
   alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        } 
 
 else if (c>a,b)
  {
   max=c;
   alert ("Max is" +" "+max);
        } `

Comment: How does it not work? What is going wrong?

Comment: So when i press the button for the last part of the function (when i got 3 numbers for the input) it s overwrite with the code from where i only got 2 numbers for the imput (i said that in the question,check the bottom)